# Liferay - Creating custom remote jsonwebservice

Tags: java, maven, liferay

I was trying to create my custom json webservice in the a spring maven portlet in the remote portal.

I came across the service.xml and Service Builder but I could only find tutorials for these relating to ant instead of maven. 
Can someone please explain here, the steps to create a basic JSON web service in a portlet, and the way I can access it from outside.

Something like

```
@JSONWebService
public class RemotePortletServiceImpl {
    public boolean fileExists(Long id) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which will return me false when I give the url in the browser (http://localhost:8081/api/jsonws/something/something)

I have been stuck with this remote service for some time now. I think there will be many out there who would find help from this.

Answer (score 0):

What you look is create a Web Service with maven ?
Which liferay version are you using?
If you are with Liferay 6.2 , maven is available for creating a Service Builder plugin, and the Web services related also.

If you are using Liferay IDE on eclipse, you can use it to create your plugin.

Also you can see this portal properties if you need to customize the security config for your web services:

JSON

```
#
# Set this property to true to activate strict mode for the JSON
# deserializer. In strict mode, the deserializer will not accept any bean
# attributes that are either static or do not comply with bean property name
# conventions (e.g. setBeanName, getBeanName).
#
json.deserializer.strict.mode=true

#
# Set this to to true to require JSON service calls to have a valid
# authentication token. This property is not used unless the property
# "auth.token.check.enabled" is also set to true.
#
json.service.auth.token.enabled=true

#
# Input a list of comma delimited IPs that can access the JSON service
# without specifying an authenticaton token. Input a blank list to allow
# any IP to access the JSON service. SERVER_IP will be replaced with the IP
# of the host server.
#
# The default value of 255.255.255.255 means that no one can access the JSON
# service without an authentication token since 255.255.255.255 is an
# invalid IP.
#
json.service.auth.token.hosts.allowed=255.255.255.255
```

JSON Web Service

```
#
# Set this property to true to enable JSON web services. Note that setting
# this to false will cause portlets that make JSON web service calls from
# working.
#
json.web.service.enabled=true

#
# Input a list of comma delimited HTTP methods that are not accessible. For
# example, if you want to have a read only API, then set this property to
# "DELETE,POST,PUT".
#
jsonws.web.service.invalid.http.methods=

#
# Set this property to true to ensure that a JSON web service action can
# only be invoked by its expected HTTP method.
#
# For example, the annotation
# com.liferay.portal.kernel.jsonwebservice.JSONWebService may configure the
# expected HTTP method for an action to be a GET request. However, the URL
# for that GET request may be too long, and so you may need to call that
# with a POST request. Setting this property to false loosens this
# requirement and allows the POST request to invoke an action that is
# supposed to only be called by a GET request.
#
jsonws.web.service.strict.http.method=false

#
# The property "jsonws.web.service.paths.excludes" denotes patterns for JSON
# web service action paths that are not allowed even if they match one of
# the patterns set in "jsonws.web.service.paths.includes".
#
jsonws.web.service.paths.excludes=

#
# The property "jsonws.web.service.paths.includes" denotes patterns for JSON
# web service action paths that are allowed. Set a blank pattern to allow
# any service action path.
#
jsonws.web.service.paths.includes=
```

Also you have this maven plugin creation tutorial:

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-maven-from-liferay-ide

Comment: I cannot find these in any .properties file. Where do I set the value of `json.web.service.enabled=true`? I have created a liferay spring maven portlet already. I just need to know how to create and enable a sample web service method, also how to make the json request call to get the response.

Comment: What Liferay version are you using? , these properties are in portal.properties file located in portal-impl.jar . You can override it , creating a portal-ext.properties and adding the properties there with your config